# How to use locale in material ui datepicker (MuiPickersUtilsProvider)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) to convert my times in js.

According to the page on [material-ui-pickers regarding localization](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/localization/calendar-systems) it gives an example on how to localize the date picker.

But no luck trying that example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
// import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import "dayjs/locale/nl";
import DayjsUtils from "@date-io/dayjs";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DayjsUtils} locale="nl">
        <KeyboardDatePicker />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-field-2gzmf

I also tried some methods as described in the generic [dayjs documentation I18n](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs#i18n), which also does not seem to work.

Does someone have an idea what's doing wrong? I feel it's something trivial.

---

After some further investigation it seems that either my implementation of dayjs is wrong, or there is a bug. Because moment JS is working, as this live example shows: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-snow-ejinu

But, on the other hand, the demo page of the Datepicker is also using moment and that isn't working: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/localization/moment

Comment: Seems that there's an issue with the locale param in the `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` component. On the demo page it also isn't working: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/localization/moment

Comment: But using the same code as on the demo page in a sandbox it will work: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-minsky-y51gy

Answer (score 28):

See my component example, its work fine with Locale of **dayjs**.

```
import React from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import ptBR from 'dayjs/locale/pt-br';
import DayJsUtils from '@date-io/dayjs';
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  KeyboardDateTimePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';

type DateTimeInputProps = {
  label: string;
  minDate?: Date;
  maxDate?: Date;
};

export const DateTimeInput = (props: DateTimeInputProps & any): JSX.Element => {
  const { label, minDate, maxDate, ...commomProps } = props;
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider locale={ptBR} utils={DayJsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDateTimePicker
        autoOk
        className="dateTimeModalPicker"
        inputVariant="outlined"
        label={label}
        placeholder="ex: DD/MM/AAAA"
        format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
        ampm={false}
        invalidDateMessage="Data em formato inválido."
        minDate={minDate}
        maxDate={maxDate}
        minDateMessage={`A data deve ser maior que ${dayjs(minDate).format(
          'DD/MM/YYYY',
        )}.`}
        maxDateMessage={`A data deve ser menor do que ${dayjs(maxDate).format(
          'DD/MM/YYYY',
        )}.`}
        cancelLabel="Cancelar"
        {...commomProps}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
```

**if you use Date-Fns:**

```
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { ptBR } from "date-fns/locale";
```

Comment: The dayjs solution throws an execption for me.
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'L')`

Comment: Have you tried using "libInstance={dayjs}" prop in MuiPickersUtilsProvider? 

eg: ```<MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={dayjs} utils={DayJsUtils} locale={ptBR}>...</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>```

Answer (score 4):

@optimizitor
When I tried this I got the error:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'dayjs/locale/ru'.

So I made a small change (removed import ru) and everything works fine:

```
import 'dayjs/locale/ru';
import { ruRU } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/locales';

<LocalizationProvider
  dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
  adapterLocale='ru'
  localeText={ruRU.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}
>
  <DatePicker />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution for `<DatePicker />` using **@mui/x-date-pickers v6.0.4** and **dayjs v1.11.7** that worked for me (you should provide corresponding locales for both the component and its adapter to have full translation):

```
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import ru from 'dayjs/locale/ru';
import { ruRU } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/locales';

<LocalizationProvider
  dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
  adapterLocale={ru}
  localeText={ruRU.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}
>
  <DatePicker />
</LocalizationProvider>
```